# Whenever setting a button movable, its becoming not clickable in android

Tags: android, button, ontouchlistener

Whenever setting a button movable, its becoming not clickable.
I can move the button but the function called with button click is not working.
I've set android:onClick="playGame" in the xml file and also defined the function playGame in class. But its not working.

If I remove the code written for movable button its working fine.

The code written for movable button is

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        float currX,currY;
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action ) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                mPrevX = event.getX();
                mPrevY = event.getY();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                currX = event.getRawX();
                currY = event.getRawY();
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());
                marginParams.setMargins((int)(currX - mPrevX), (int)(currY - mPrevY),0, 0);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The code is working fine for moving buttons but the buttons are becoming not clickable.

Comment: The reason why click event is not working because you are consuming the onTouch event completely by returning 'true', you should create one flag say 'boolean consumed = false' and change to true on Move, otherwise leave that as false. and finally return consumed. It might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should distinguish move from click in your `onTouchEvent()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;//!!
    private long startClickTime; //!!

    ... 
    switch (action ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();//!!

            ...
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            ...
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
            if(clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                //click event has occurred
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I can't use `onClick()` functions inside this cause in  `onCreate` function I need to set buttons clickable and in `onClickListener` event I need the seperate `onClick` operations. Will this do my job?

Comment: no need  for `onClickListener `, just put inside action_up :  Log.v("","On Item Clicked:: ");  inside if (clickDuration..){  here  }

Comment: then this code can't be used for different button click functions right. What I'm doing is writing this code in the base class and the classes which are extending the base class can operate movable. If I specify the button click here then
 (i) xml animation of the button_pressed will not work
 (ii) I have to right this entire code for different button clicks.
I guess... If I'm not wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gesture detector to separate the logic.

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    your_button_view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(arg1)) {
                // single tap
                return true;
            } else {
                // your code for move and drag
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```